# For each div, find ul and count number tables row. Append this value back to parent in p tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list on my website which has list inside called `.cart-items`. The cart items contains a table with numerous rows. I want to be able to go through each of the `.cart-select` list items and count how many `tr` are within the cart-items. I then want to print this number out just before the `.list` on each `.cart-select`.

I've added the below  but the it's returning as 0. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

```js
$('.cart-select').each(function() {
  var products = $('.list .cart-items', this).find('tr').length;
  $('<p>' + products + '</p>').appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="cart-select">
    <ul class="list">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="cart-items">
        <table>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="cart-select">
    <ul class="list">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="cart-items">
        <table>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: well it seems to work though..

Comment: Your code works fine, you just need to use `prependTo()` instead of `appendTo()`:http://jsfiddle.net/k5ca7tz6/

Comment: Works fine for me, it returns 2 for both instances

Comment: _“but the it's returning as 0”_ - nope, it isn’t: http://jsfiddle.net/b61m4un4/ Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try these :

```js
$('.cart-select').each(function() {
  var products = $('.list .cart-items', this).find('tr').length;
  $('<p>' + products + '</p>').appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="cart-select">
    <ol class="list">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="cart-items">
        <table>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="cart-select">
    <ol class="list">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="cart-items">
        <table>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine when tested in stack snippets:

> I then want to print this number out just before the .list on each
>   .cart-select.

You need to use `prependTo();` instead of `appendTo();`

```js
$('.cart-select').each(function() {
  var products = $('.list .cart-items', this).find('tr').length;
  $('<p>' + products + '</p>').prependTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="cart-select">
  <ul class="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="cart-items">
      <table>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
      </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="cart-select">
  <ul class="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="cart-items">
      <table>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
      </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an easy way to make it, try this:

```js
$('.cart-items').each(function() {
      var products = $(this).find("tr").size()
      $(this).closest(".cart-select").prepend('<p>' + products + '</p>')
})
```

```css
p{
 color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="cart-select">
         <ul class="list">
            <li>Li 1</li>
            <li>Li 2</li>
            <li>Li 3</li>
            <li class="cart-items">Li 4<br><br>
                <table>
                  <tr>Tr 1</tr><br>
                  <tr>Tr 2</tr><br>
                  <tr>Tr 3</tr><br>
                  <tr>Tr 4</tr>
                </table>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>

<li class="cart-select">
         <ul class="list">
            <li>Li 1</li>
            <li>Li 2</li>
            <li>Li 3</li>
            <li class="cart-items">Li 4<br><br>
                <table>
                  <tr>Tr 1</tr><br>
                  <tr>Tr 2</tr>
                </table>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
```